# Customize the display for organic group forum

Tags: organic-groups, nodes

I am using [Organic groups](http://drupal.org/project/og), and I would like to change the way forum topics are displayed. More precisely, I would like to be able to add a block that shows [WebFM](http://drupal.org/project/webfm) attachments.

One way that I've found is to customize the "Node template" page (the one used for the path **`/node/%node`**) and create a variant whose selection rule takes "Forum topic" as node type. There I can customize the layout and the content, also adding the WebFM block.

I wonder if there's an easier and more straightforward way of doing this.